# How to take screenshots from a generic ICS 7" tablet?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet, screenshots

I want to know how to take a screenshot on a generic Ice Cream Sandwich tablet? I believe this certain model is called the XTOUCH X708S. I already tried pressing `power button` + `volume down` and it just does its respective functionalities without taking any screenshots. The owner isn't very literate when it comes to Android devices so she doesn't know how to either.

Comment: How long did you keep the buttons pressed? On some devices it's just a question of timing, and I remember some have proven a bit tricky with that.

Comment: As soon as I pressed `power` or `volume down` it would either prompt me to shut down the tablet or lower the volume until it reaches the lowest volume possible. I also tried holding it for an extend amount of time and it just stayed that way.

Comment: You have to press both buttons simultaneously (not first one, then the other). Assuming you know that and have done so, I'd suggest contacting the support staff.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the back button for 3 seconds. Still holding the back button press the power button once and release both buttons.

Comment: I tried to do that just now and it just turns off the display. I also tried varying lengths of holding down the on-screen back button. Still no go.